# Why R cannot read this table while excel can?

Tags: r

I am trying to read a specific file that I have copied from an SFTP location. The file is pipe delimited. I can read the file in Excel. But R read is as null values and column names are being duplicated. I don't understand if this is an encoding issue? I am trying to create a bash script to automate this process. Any help? Below is the link for the data.

Here's [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L7wmHbgb5dra442iscCaEO0PsRMXzpDR/view?usp=sharing)!

I have tried changing the Encoding. But without knowing which encoding I am struggling. I have tried using read_delim, ead_table, read.table, read_csv and read.csv. But no help.

this is the code I have used to read the file.

```
read_delim("./Engagement_Level.txt", delim = "|")
```

I would like to read it as a data frame.

Comment: Hi Amal. I would suggest that asking people to download a random Google drive file is not the best way to get help for your question. It would be much better if you provided a more easily verified file, e.g., a reproducible subset of your data that can be viewed in Github.

Comment: Hi  @heds1, thanks for the suggestion. But the problem is that I am unable to create a reproducible subset of the data as I am not able to read it into R in the first case. Secondly, a subset created in R would be easily readable by R, so I won't be recreating the instance. Hence the data link in google sheets. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the file encoding is UTF-16LE, which `read_delim` cannot read at present.

You could use the base `read.delim` and `file()` to specify the encoding:

```
read.delim(file("Engagement_Level.txt", encoding = "UTF-16LE"), sep = "|")
```

That will convert all the quoted numbers to numeric. If you'd rather they were type character, to deal with later:

```
read.delim(file("Engagement_Level.txt", encoding = "UTF-16LE"), sep = "|", 
                colClasses = "character")
```

Comment: Great!!!, That works. But how did you find the Encoding of the file is "UTF-16LE" ?

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend you to use Excel to build a CSV file using **Data>Text in columns**, this is not appropriate in this context but it's incredibly infallible and quickly.

Then use `read.csv(file,sep=",")`.